# What is the preferred way to load data from an API into BigQuery?

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl

I am trying to get data from a REST API into BigQuery on the Google Cloud Platform (GCP). What is the best way to achieve that (without using any third party tools such as Funnel.io or Supermetrics)?

Most tutorials I could find suggest to write the data as CSV files to Cloud Storage and then use DataFlow to load the data into BigQuery. This however seems to be a bit cumbersome. There should be a way to do that without the intermediate step to write to CSV. Can this be achieved (within GCP) and if so, what is the best way?

*PS: If the size of the data is relevant for the answer: I'm trying to load a total of about 10,000 rows of data (one-off) with about 100 new columns coming in every day - ideally updating every hour.*

Comment: Have you studied the following ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_table_insert_rows-python ... will this not work for you?

Comment: I can't see why this question has been closed. It says "This question needs to be more focused". After reading up on the documentation, the question neither "includes multiple questions in one", nor does it have "many valid answers". In fact, the question is very focused on a specific question and includes only one valid answer. Could you please reconsider to reopen the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the hint by @Kolban above, loading data from an API into BigQuery without using third party tools and without writing an intermediate file to Google Cloud Storage is possible, and indeed quite simple, by "streaming" data into BigQuery:

```
rows_to_insert = [(u"Phred Phlyntstone", 32), (u"Wylma Phlyntstone", 29)]

errors = client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)  # Make an API request.
if errors == []:
    print("New rows have been added.")
```

(From the [BQ documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_table_insert_rows-python))

In order to prepare the JSON data, it has to be turned into tuples. Here's an excerpt from my code to achieve this:

```
# Turn JSON into tuples
data_tuples = []
for key,value in resp_json[product_id].items():
    data_tuples.append((
        value["product_id"],
        value["downloads"]
        )
    )

# Insert into BQ
errors = client.insert_rows(table, data_tuples)
if errors == []:
    print("New rows have been added.")
else:
    print(errors)
```

Comment: I was wondering what are the options to schedule this script to run regularly? Are you using AWS?

Comment: I think this is something for a new question. But in short, we use Airflow for that.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#limitations):

> Currently, you can load data into BigQuery only from Cloud Storage or
> a readable data source (such as your local machine).

Therefore, unless you are loading Datastore or Firestore exports, it is required that the files are in Google Cloud Storage. There are the following available readable formats from GCS:

> Avro
>
> CSV
>
> JSON (newline delimited only)
>
> ORC
>
> Parquet
>
> Datastore exports
>
> Firestore exports

You should be aware of the [limitations for each format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#limitations). In addition, there are also limitations for load jobs, they are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs).

I would advice you to fetch the data from your Rest API, in one of the readable formats, store it in Google Cloud Storage then use Google Transfer Service to load it into BigQuery. Thus, it would not be necessary to use DataFlow.

Cloud Storage Transfer is used to schedule recurring data loads directly into BigQuery. According to the documentation, the minimum load interval is 1 hour, which I believe suits your need. You can read more about this service [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer).

I hope it helps.

Comment: While you can only "Load" data into BQ using Cloud Storage, you can in fact also "Stream" data into BQ: "Instead of using a job to load data into BigQuery, you can choose to stream your data into BigQuery" (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery)